# Element moves faster the farther the mouse is moved

Tags: html, canvas

I'm on the way to make my own browser game with HTML5 and Canvas. But now I have a problem with some variables in this code.

```
mousemove++;

velX = (tx1 / dist1) * speed;
velY = (ty1 / dist1) * speed;
velX = velX;
velY = velY;

posX1 += velX;
posY1 += velY;

backgroundX -= velX;
backgroundY -= velY;
backgroundX1 -= velX*background_factor;
backgroundY1 -= velY*background_factor;

var playerX1 = 960-backgroundX1;
var playerY1 = 461-backgroundY1;
playerX = playerX1;
playerY = playerY1;
```

When I move the player with my mouseover event, the player is much faster when I move the mouse more and more. I tried already to make this from the velX and velY variables... velX = velX/1.6; But this is not the right way to solve this problem, because there are much variables that could change. When someone needs more informations about my code I would gave it, but for the moment I hope someone have the right solution for my problem :/

Comment: How is `dist1` defined? Because if it tends to 0 then velX diverges. Same for `tx1`, is it a constant or it increases on each game loop?

Comment: It redefines everytime when the user clicks on the map or moves the mouse, here is the code for this :)                                                            `var tx1 = newX - posX1;
var ty1 = newY - posY1;
var dist1 = Math.sqrt(tx1 * tx1 + ty1 * ty1);`